# How to check if a session or cookie has been set?

Tags: php, cookies, authentication

pretty much I have a loggin:

and it checks if someone is logged in as a session or a cookie(remember me)

I tried:

```
    if(isset($_SESSION['username']) || isset($_COOKIES['username']{
```

eetc..

But it does not work.. any help?

Comment: You do have more code than that, right? For starters, is `session_start();` loaded?

Comment: Yes session start is loaded in a functions file @Fred-ii-

Comment: You'll need to provide more code than that. Just one line isn't enough. In the meantime, try `if(isset($_SESSION['username']) || isset($_COOKIES['username'])){` your brackets are a bit off. @user3586915 If needed, you could also change `||` to `&&` if checking explicitly for both. `||` is `OR` while `&&` is `AND`

Comment: debug `print_r($_SESSION);print_r($_COOKIES);`

Comment: So @user3586915 did `if(isset($_SESSION['username']) || isset($_COOKIES['username'])){` work? It theoretically should.

Comment: I guess either the OP's house caught fire, or is late for a very important meeting @Dagon Pass the popcorn, go easy on the salt ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**This is not the exact code but will help you out.**

You can try few things and checkout if you are getting anything in the cookies file

```
<?php
// Print a cookie
echo $_COOKIE["user"];

// A way to view all cookies
print_r($_COOKIE);
?>
```

If you are getting values from above then you run this code

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE["user"]))
  echo "Welcome " . $_COOKIE["user"] . "!<br>";
else
  echo "Welcome guest!<br>";
?>
```

Comment: (*In so many words*) Dagon already said that in a [`one-liner`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23374717/how-to-check-if-a-session-or-cookie-has-been-set#comment35805732_23374717) --- *Plus,* you're not even checking for the session, only the cookie.